# One of the soldiers heads off to relay information - head off - meaning

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/ukraine-field-troops-prepare-assault-donetsk-200929804.html

> A group squeezed into an old Lada car returns from a reconnaissance mission. One of the soldiers **heads off** to relay information.

What does that mean in this context?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/head_off
"To begin moving away"

Comment: Did you look up _head off_ in a dictionary? If so, were there more than one definition of _head off?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To head off" means to leave or go.

Answer (score 1):

To go -

E.g., "I'm heading off to the shops" = "I'm going to the shops"; "I'm heading off now" = "I'm going/leaving now".